# What versions of C allow you to declare variables in for loops?

Tags: c, for-loop, gcc, c99, c11

Ever since I began coding in C, I was taught that

```
for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
...
```

worked in C++, but in C you must declare the variable outside of the for loop like so:

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<10;++i)
...
```

I *specifically* remember this being a problem because I was used to C++ for loops when I began coding in C.

But today I was reading the December 2010 draft of the C11 standard, and it defined the for loop as

"for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement"

and in it's description of syntax it noted:

"If clause-1 is a **declaration**, the scope of any identifiers it declares is the remainder of the declaration and
the entire loop".

THEN I did a test and realized that my gcc (Debian 8.3.0) compiles for loops in the C++ style in -std=c99, AND in -std=c11 mode with no warnings even with the -Wall flag.

Is this a gcc extension, or has C supported this type of loop for a while and I just didn't notice?

Comment: It's the latter : )

Comment: You are likely to be one of the many victims of C teachers teaching on Windows as MSVC didn't support the quite old C99 for over a decade in "C mode" but did support the very same extensions to C89 in "C-++ mode", hence many having the view that you can't mix declarations and other statements in C etc. However, most of those quality-of-coding features are in C nowadays (well, for 20 years already)

Comment: And lets not mention the severely incompetent teachers that still teaches MS DOS programming in Borland Turbo C to this day...

Comment: And if you feel betrayed by that, also check out "compound literals". The truth will set you free.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was standardized in C99

from: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/for

> (C99) If it is a declaration, it is in scope in the entire loop body,
>   including the remainder of init_clause, the entire cond_expression,
>   the entire iteration_expression and the entire loop_statement. Only
>   auto and register storage classes are allowed for the variables
>   declared in this declaration.