# Are overlapping C for loop variable definitions allowed?

Tags: c, for-loop, gcc, c99, c11

Recently, I accidentally wrote C code that looks like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < SOME_VALUE; ++i)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ANOTHER_VALUE; ++i)
    {
        // do work with 'i' from inner loop *WITHOUT* any disruption to 'i' from outer loop
    }
}
```

Reading the code closely, I discovered this "bug".  However, at runtime, it did not cause any issues.  To be clear, my code was compiled with a relatively recent version of MinGW-w64 to create a native Win32 binary.

Sure, the code works, but I am surprised this is allowed, and even more surprised that my GCC-ish compiler did not complain about it!  (Is there a GCC warning option for this mistake?)

Can someone explain why this is allowed, and why the inner and outer `i` variables do not conflict / disrupt?  Ideally, someone can point me to official ISO-ish C language definition that allows (and supports) this behaviour!

Inspired by: [What versions of C allow you to declare variables in for loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61766190/what-versions-of-c-allow-you-to-declare-variables-in-for-loops)

Comment: Called shadowing. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32254127/c-prevent-use-of-same-variable-name-in-block-scope

Comment: This is just variable shadowing

Comment: Variables in the inner block will simply shadow outer ones with the same name. This has always been allowed in C.

Comment: Shadowing variables in inner scopes is absolutely standard and normal (though often discouraged for the reasons you've found).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25151524/695132

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is allowed, and is commonly referred to as *shadowing*, where the variable at the innermost scope shadows any variable with the same name at an outer scope.

This is explicitly allowed as specified in section 6.2.1p4 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding Scope of Identifiers:

> ... If an identifier designates two different entities in the same
> name space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity
> (the *inner scope*) will end strictly before the scope of the other
> entity (the *outer scope*). Within the inner scope, the identifier
> designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared
> in the outer scope is *hidden* (and not visible) within the inner scope.

Comment: It is called “hiding” in the C standard, not “shadowing”. There is no darkness (blocking of light) cast upon previous identifiers. Rather, they are not visible, hence hidden.

Comment: *shadow* in common usage means the opposite of what you're saying in *the variable at the innermost scope shadows any variable with the same name*. It's typically used to mean a person or thing in another's shadow, not the one casting a shadow, e.g.: *the new guy is going to shadow you for the next few days to get up to speed.*

Comment: The name of the gcc warning is `-Wshadow`.